# How to make polars in python not quote anything in write_csv?

Tags: python

I'm generating a javascript data file in polars and when writing it out, I'd like polars NOT to quote anything.
How can I do that?
This is still quoting (and quote parameter cannot be None or empty):

```
import polars as pl
data = ['// 2023.09.01.',
        'var mydata = [',
        '[11.407538,22.003241,51,,"L","T",,67',
        '[12.547899,21.033232,112,,"L","T",,139',
        '];']
df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema=['X'])
df.write_csv('myfile.js', has_header = False, quote_style = None)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you write a javascript code using polars?

Comment: Not javascript code, javascript data file.

Comment: `var mydata = [` definitely looks like part of code.

Comment: Don't treat data as code and vice versa - that will make things way more complicated than they should be down the line. `json` is a perfect format for storing data that can be later easily loaded into JS without being extremely fragile.

Comment: What matszwecja said. Note that polars has a `df.write_json()` method: https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_json.html

Comment: It is a legacy thing, and I would not like to rewrite it from scratch now. Anyway, I solved it with replace() and re.sub(), just wanted to know if I'm missing some functionality on write_csv here...